# Export/Import RRDtool database with differents RRA

Tags: data-migration, rrdtool

I have a RRDTool database that has data inside and I want to be able to import this data into another RRDTool database that differs only by the RRAs.

I want to increase the precision of historical data, so I tried how to grow the RRA via [rrdresize](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrdresize.en.html) but it doesn't recompute the added rows. That means I get strange results when graphing as various "zoom levels" : the graph has data when graphing at a lower precision, but empty when I increase the precision since RRDTool automatically selects the best precision level, and the newly added RRA rows are empty (*UNKNOWN*).

I cannot use [rrdrestore](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrdrestore.en.html) either since that also creates the RRD (and doesn't just fill an already existing one).

I know that I cannot recreate the lost data, but I would like to at least copy the data from the lower precision RRA to the new high precision one.

I did write a simple tool, [rrdmove](http://code.google.com/p/pmptools/source/browse/trunk/rrd/rrdmove), that just loops on every step to do a rrdfetch/rrdupdate cycle so that RRDTool just recomputes all the RRA in the new database, but it does not seem very efficient.

Answer (score 1):

do you still have that script/tool you mentioned?
I'm looking for the same thing, but I'm okay with something less efficient.

Edit: I found a pretty cool (I think) tool:  http://docs.cacti.net/manual:087:8_rrdtool.04_resize
but I still need to get it to work.

Comment: Thanks Steve.  I know none of this helps you any further, but your script turns out be to be quite useful for me.
See http://dieter.plaetinck.be/RRDtool_updating_RRA_settings_and_keeping_your_collected_data
if anyone suggests me a better approach, i'll set you know.

And in the worst case, maybe librrd can help you out:
http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/librrd.en.html